# Open source development life cycle

Tags: design

I am working as a IT-developer. I am developing J2EE application in our own life project cycle methodology.

I have seen and learnt so many SDLC cycle models in order to develop a project but this open source development and its process still unknown to me.

So, how this open source development life cycle happen? How this life bring a powerfull products like Hibernate, Spring , Struts etc...

How can i contribute as a developer in these popular frameworks.?

Comment: @DanPichelman : Thanks a lot. Yes duplicate. I did google this topic but I didnt get this link.

Comment: You may want to read the famous essay: "The cathedral and the bazaar" http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/homesteading/

Answer (score 0):

Open vs close source doesn't necessarily dictate anything when it comes to the development process. So... pick whatever floats your boat. Or get used to whatever the particular project is using.

Or don't. You can buck their process and fork your own build with your own process. That's how Ubuntu came to be. A group was miffed at Debian's long release cycle.